# How to add songs to ipod from ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, music, ipod, itunes

How can i add songs to my ipod from ubuntu 13.10. Is there any softwares similar to itunes.
I tried gtkpod ipod manager for adding music to my ipod but it crashes every time i try to add songs to ipod.Is there any other way to add songs to ipod?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be No! You cannot load music on your iPod with 13.10. I have tried every program I could find, and none of them seem to work. gtkpod crashes so often it is unusable. It is not clear to me that it does anything. Rhythmbox crashes frequently also. With Rhythmbox you cannot create new playlists on the device. They have removed every facility you used to use to do this. I cannot find a way to do it. Banshee deleted all of my playlists and also crashes a lot. Something is very wrong with this release. (This subject has not been good since about 10.04.) Best bet: go buy a Mac! I can't get Ubuntu to work with an iPod.

Comment: you are right.when i tried to add music from rhythmbox it crashes and my ipods album arts got the place of other songs and the shuffling system didn't work.so i had to restore my songs from windows

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was to install Banshee Media Player. I formatted the ipod for windows first using virtualbox and Windows 7 with the *apple software*- If this is a fresh out of the box ipod you will need to do this and remember to enable USB2 devices on your virtual machine. After that you should be able to drag things your Banshee library onto your ipod - ensure you have enabled the ipod support plugin in Banshee. Rhythmbox has never been that great with ipods so I have not tried that yet on my install.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible but you will requires software like [crossweaver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/) which enable you to install windows software like itunes and your good to go.